Команда pwsh в Visual Studio
В ходе реализации проекта возникла ошибка, которая подразумевает установку дополнительных пакетов или расширений. В общем, так как не работал ранее с visual studio, не могу понять куда прописывается команда.
Ошибка звучит следующим образом:

Looks like Playwright was just installed or updated. Please
run the following command to download new browsers:
pwsh bin/Debug/netX/playwright.ps1 install


Не думаю, что этой команде нужна студия. Откройте папку с проектом (где файл csprog и папка bin), в адресной строке напишите cmd, в появившееся окно вставьте команду. Если всеж там есть что-то специфичное для студии, то открываете проект в студии, сверху ищите поиск, в нем пишете PowerShell, находите там "PowerShell для разработчиков", ну и в это окно уже команду. Замечу: 1. netX - тут скорей всего надо указать нужную версию. 2. playwright как и selenium созданы для тестирования свои сайтов, а не для парсинга. Если вы занимаетесь последним, то изучите лучше HttpClient.

да, powershell находил, команду вставлял, но выдает ошибку:
pwsh : Имя "pwsh" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы.
Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

pwsh bin/Debug/net7.0/playwright.ps1 install



CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pwsh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


значит у вас "кастрированная" или старая OS. Попробуйте полное имя powershell а не сокращенное pwsh.

powershell нашел, но теперь ругается на сам адрес:
bin/Debug/net7.0/playwright.ps1 : Имя "bin/Debug/net7.0/playwright.ps1" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файл
а сценария или выполняемой программы.

Ну чтож вы так, должна быть ведь хоть доля самостоятельности. Что мешает поискать информацию по powershell run ps1 file?, найдете уйму способов запуска, например... powershell -File .\bin... install или просто .\bin... install. Я ведь не знаю что у вас там. Вот я скопировал команду, вставил что в консоль, что в студию, у меня все нашло и отработало, а это значит, что вы должны под себя подобрать подходящий способ вызова команды, так будет банально быстрее и надежней...
